# Как разместить img по центру страницы (text-align: center; не работает)

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Задумал сделать сайт но мне нужно чтоб слайдер расположился по центру но его прижимает к левой стороне. Зарание спасиба!

```js
<script>
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showDivs(slideIndex);

        function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
        }

        function showDivs(n) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    background-image: url('fon2.png');
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.button_sys{
    text-align: center;
}
.next, .back{
    padding: 0px 5% 0px 5%;
}
.image_menu{
    text-align: center;
}
.podlogka{
    padding: 150px;
}
footer {
    padding-top: 50% 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);  
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Some site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="news.html">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>

    <div class="image_sys">
        <div>
            <a href="#20" class="image_menu"><img src="Kompass_logo.png" class="mySlides" width="350px"></a>
            <a href="#30" class="image_menu"><img src="photoshop_logo.png" class="mySlides" width="350px"></a>
            <a href="#40" class="image_menu"><img src="powerpoint_logo.png" class="mySlides" width="350px"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button_sys">
        <a class="next" onclick="plusDivs(+1)"><img src="back_p.png" alt="back" width="100px"></a>
        <a class="back" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"><img src="next_p.png" alt="next" width="100px"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="podlogka">
        <p> </p>
    </div>
    <footer><p>Some Info</p></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Попробовал margin: 0 auto; но ничего не поменялось(

Comment: Возможно я неправильно делаю (я новенький, позавчера начал учить) но у меня не работает (display: block; margin: 0 auto)
body{
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    background-image: url('fon2.png');
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

Answer (score 0):

image_sys - если,  не ошибаюсь слайдер.
Для размещения по центру страницы один из вариантов сделать элемент блочным, прописав в css
.image_sys { display: block; margin: 0 auto }

или непосредственно в html

```
<div style="display: block; margin: 0 auto">
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: К сожалению нет. Возможно я неправильно делаю (я новенький, ток позавчера решил учить) но ничего не работает

Comment: Попробовал и в css и html но слайдер так и прибит к левому краю

Answer (score 0):

```
.image_sys {
  width: 1200px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000
}
```

Но вообще, если мало опыта в разработке, лучше использовать, что-то типа Bootstrap | https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/

Comment: Попробовал этот метод но теперь черный прямоугольник а с левой стороны находиться слайдер.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
}
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    background-image: url('fon2.png');
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav a {
    /* float: left; */
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.button_sys{
    text-align: center;
}
.next, .back{
    padding: 0px 5% 0px 5%;
}
.image_menu{
    text-align: center;
}
.podlogka{
    padding: 150px;
}
footer {
    padding-top: 50% 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);  
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="news.html">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div class="image_sys">
    <div >
        <a href="#20" class="image_menu"><img src="Kompass_logo.png" class="mySlides" width="350px"></a>
        <a href="#30" class="image_menu"><img src="photoshop_logo.png" class="mySlides" width="350px"></a>
        <a href="#40" class="image_menu"><img src="powerpoint_logo.png" class="mySlides" width="350px"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="button_sys">
    <a class="next" onclick="plusDivs(+1)"><img src="back_p.png" alt="back" width="100px"></a>
    <a class="back" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"><img src="next_p.png" alt="next" width="100px"></a>
</div>
<div class="podlogka">
    <p> </p>
</div>
<footer><p>Some Info</p></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.image_sys > div {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
.image_sys div { text-align:center;}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]